# Just basic MySQL doubts that needs to be cleared

Tags: mysql, database

There are 2 questions:

1. How to extract numbers from string such as 'R1001'?
2. How to convert 2,50,000 to 250000?

For the first question i tried the code: select substr(roid,2) as numericroid from retailoutet;
Expectation: 1001 for R1001
Output I Got: table/view does not exist.

For the second question i tried code: to_number('2,50,000','9,99,999')
Expectation: 250000
Output: Error Invaid Number

Comment: mysql does not have to_number function. Oracle does but it's not always possible to drop oracle code into mysql and have it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query
**for the first question**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('R1001', '[^0-9]', '') AS numeric_string;
```

**for the second question**

```
SELECT REPLACE('2,50,000', ',', '') AS converted_number;
```